# Unable to use azure SDK in Python

Tags: python, azure

I did this:

```
sudo pip install azure azure-storage azure-servicebus azure-mgmt azure-servicemanagement-legacy

from azure import *
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named azure

```
from azure.storage import BlobService
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named azure.storage

Comment: Which platform and python version you're using?

Comment: I tried with both Ubuntu 14 and OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python package installed thru cmd `sudo pip install` exists at the paths `/usr/lib/python2.7`, `/usr/local/python2.7`, etc and their sub-folder `dist-packages`.

You can code `import sys` and `print sys.path` in the Python Interpreter to show the completed path list for current python environment.

Iif you installed successfully some packages like `azure` & `azure-storage`, you can find these files relate to the package in the python library paths.

However, you got the error `in Import Error: No module named <package-name>` when you run the code `import <package-name>` or `from <package-name> import <class or object name>`. There are two scenes that would be cause the issue normally.

1. Package not installed successfully.
2. The library path included package that not exists in Python system environment path `sys.path` in python or `PYTHONHOME` in environment variables.

So I think you can try to solve the issue thru three ways below.

1. Dynamically add the package path into `sys.path` thru the method `sys.path.append('<package path>')` in python code.
2. Check the environment variable `PYTHONHOME` whether or not set up. If set up `PYTHONHOME`, python will add package path based on `PYTHONHOME` into `sys.path`.
3. If your python environment encounter some unknown fault that is unrecoverable, you can try to reinstall Python thru commands `sudo apt-get remove python python-pip`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install python python-pip` on Ubuntu. It's a simple way.

Comment: this will work - but isn't the best way - OP is trying to use deprecated meta packages in this case

Answer (score 1):

BlobService belongs to azure.storage.blob rather than the azure.storage

it should rather be

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
```

Link - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/

If it still doesn't work for you, you might would like to use virtualEnv and do the pip install again while in virtualenv

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name BlobService

Comment: didi you PIP install finished without errors, I just tested this works really fine, or you can use virtualenv create a diff folder and do a pip install in it - fresh

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar issue. There was a lot of confusion between python2 and python3 package versions as there was no virtual env used and I also had to ungrade pip to 18.

But anyway, this is is how I resolved the part in question.

Locate where the package was installed:

```
pip show azure
```

The output will show the location of the package in the *Location* section:

```
Name: azure
Version: 4.0.0
Summary: Microsoft Azure Client Libraries for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python
Author: Microsoft Corporation
Author-email: azpysdkhelp@microsoft.com
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: azure-servicefabric, azure-cosmosdb-table, azure-datalake-store, azure-loganalytics, azure-eventgrid, azure-servicemanagement-legacy, azure-servicebus, azure-graphrbac, azure-storage-blob, azure-mgmt, azure-storage-file, azure-batch, azure-applicationinsights, azure-keyvault, azure-storage-queue
Required-by:
```

If you do:

```
python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
```

You will see a list of pip package locations:

```
['/app', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

At the begining of my python file I added:

```
sys.path.insert( 0, '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages' )
```

This will make sure this package location will be checked in the first place.

**UPDATE**

Thinking about it in the morning, things opened from a new perspective for me. I saw, that I had `#!/usr/bin/python` at the beginning of my python file, which says to use the wrong interpreter and look for pip packages in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

azure metapackage is deprecated
and azure-storage is not being maintained anymore

Please use azure-storage-blob >= 12.0

```
pip install azure-storage-blob
```

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
```

PS: I write SDKs for azure