# Import azure.servicebus error in Python

Tags: python, azure, import, python-import, azureservicebus

I'm using the module azure.servicebus.

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService , Message , Queue
```

When I use it in an external made script and run it, it works and gives no errors.

When I import the module in my **init**.py file and run the flask server. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
app = server.OpSoRoApplication()
File "/home/pi/OnoSW/server.py", line 101, in __init__
plugin = self.plugin_source.load_plugin(plugin_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluginbase.py", line 272, in load_plugi           n
globals(), {}, ['__name__'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluginbase.py", line 404, in plugin_imp           ort
fromlist, level)
File "/home/pi/OnoSW/./apps/assistant/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
import IFTTT
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluginbase.py", line 404, in plugin_imp           ort
fromlist, level)
File "/home/pi/OnoSW/IFTTT.py", line 1, in <module>
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService , Message , Queue
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluginbase.py", line 404, in plugin_imp           ort
fromlist, level)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/__init__.py", line 39,            in <module>
from .servicebusservice import ServiceBusService
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluginbase.py", line 404, in plugin_imp           ort
fromlist, level)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py",            line 46, in <module>
from ._common_serialization import (
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluginbase.py", line 404, in plugin_imp           ort
fromlist, level)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/_common_serialization.           py", line 31, in <module>
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape as xml_escape
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluginbase.py", line 404, in plugin_imp           ort
fromlist, level)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from xmlreader import InputSource
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluginbase.py", line 404, in plugin_imp           ort
fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named xmlreader
```

Can someone help to figure out how I can make it possible to be able to import the azure.servicebus module?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ServiceBusService is deprecated in v7.0.0 https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/7.0.0/

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
```

Answer (score 1):

For people stumbling upon this question now having the same problem:

Azure SDK updates often does and has introduced breaking changes:
0.2 -> 0.5:

```
# From azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService <- This will now raise an ImportError
from azure.servicebus.control_client import ServiceBusService
```

0.5 -> 7.0.0

```
#from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService <-- Now outdated
from azure.servicebus.management import ServiceBusAdministrationClient
```

This is however not enough: Make sure to check further API changes in this migration guide: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/migration_guide.md

Comment: doesn't work : "ImportError: No module named control_client"
May be they changed again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar SO thread answered by me, which I think you can refer to, and try to solve the issue, please see [Unable to use azure SDK in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213764/unable-to-use-azure-sdk-in-python).

Meanwhile, per my experience, I suggest that you need to check whether the name conflict with `xmlreader` for python modules and scripts exists, please refer to the answer for the SO thread [ImportError: cannot import name Session, when using Azure SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781904/importerror-cannot-import-name-session-when-using-azure-sdk).

Hope it helps. Any update, please feel free to let me know.